# Is there a user defined typeguard for requiring elements in an array?

Tags: arrays, typescript, tuples, typescript-generics

I am looking for a user defined type guard which would determine whether an array contains nullable or optional elements. I have written a helper type for `RequiredArray`:

```js
type RequiredArray<A extends readonly any[]> =
    A extends [infer P, ...infer R]
    ? [NonNullable<P>, ...RequiredArray<R>]
    : []
```

This seems to work. However when I try to write a typeguard for it...

```js
function arrIsFullyDefined<Arr extends readonly any[]>(arr: Arr): arr is RequiredArray<Arr> {
    return arr.every((e) => e !== null && e !== undefined);
}
```

Typescript complains about a possible instantiation of a different type:

```
A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
  Type 'RequiredArray<Arr>' is not assignable to type 'Arr'.
    'RequiredArray<Arr>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Arr', but 'Arr' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'any[]'.
      Type '[] | [unknown]' is not assignable to type 'Arr'.
        '[] | [unknown]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Arr', but 'Arr' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'any[]'.
          Type '[]' is not assignable to type 'Arr'.
            '[]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Arr', but 'Arr' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'any[]'.
              Type '[]' is not assignable to type 'Arr'.
                '[]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Arr', but 'Arr' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'any[]'.ts(2677)
```

At first I thought this was an issue with a potentially infinite array type being assigned to the `Arr` generic, however checking for this in the `RequiredArray` type (using `IsFinite` from [typescript-tuple](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-tuple)) gave the same result.
My question is:

1. Why does this cause the error?
2. How can I write a typeguard for this helper?

Comment: `arr is Arr & RequiredArray<Arr>`

Comment: @LindaPaiste Thank you very much. Do you know how I can require the `Arr` type to be a tuple? Right now it accepts arrays as well (`any[]`). I need it to accept `[1,2,3]` only, not `(1|2|3)[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Linda for the solution:

```js
type _RequiredArray<Arr extends readonly any[]> =
    Arr extends [infer P, ...infer R]
    ? [NonNullable<P>, ..._RequiredArray<R>]
    : [];

type RequiredArray<Arr extends readonly any[]> = Arr & _RequiredArray<Arr>;
```